# Checkbox/Radio onChange event not returning the standard event object (Only if React-plus-Carbon)

Tags: reactjs

I'm just starting with React, combined with the Carbon Design System from IBM (https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/).  My problem is that Checkbox and RadioButton components do not return the same {event} object to my onChange handler as that returned by straight React/JSX.  Carbon DOES match React on TextInput and Select components.

The behavior is similar to the issue in [React onChange event doesnt return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112712/react-onchange-event-doesnt-return-object).  However, that is referencing React Toolbox and Material Design, which I am not using.

The difference can be seen in Carbon's online sandbox tool. An example of a radio button is at http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=RadioButton&selectedStory=Default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel.  Click the button and see the results returned in the Action Logger panel.  Compare to results of changing (not just clicking) a text input in http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=TextInput&selectedStory=Default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel.  The problem element returns {event} as the third element down, while the good one returns only one element containing the {event} as desired.  Apparently, Carbon is only passing along the first element.

Below is the change handler, the ReactJSX, and the resulting HTML.

```
    handleChange(event) {
        console.log(event)
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        this.setState({[name]: value}) 
    }
```

```
<RadioButton 
    id="gender-male"
    name="gender"
    labelText="Male (Carbon)"
    labelPosition="right"
    value="male"
    checked={this.state.gender === "male"}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

```
<div class="bx--radio-button-wrapper">
   <input 
      id="gender-male" 
      name="gender" 
      type="radio" 
      class="bx--radio-button" 
      value="male"
   >

   <label for="gender-male" 
      class="bx--radio-button__label" 
      aria-label="Male (Carbon)">
      <span class="bx--radio-button__appearance"></span>
      <span class="">Male (Carbon)</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

The expected behavior is for Local Scope to contain an event object with properties for name, value, type, checked, etc.  But for Carbon's RadioButton and Checkbox, Local Scope contains only a flat text of the element's value, no object at all.

Global Scope does seem to contain the full object.  But I hesitate to reference outside of Local, and it seems wrong to have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is straight from the `RadioButton` component of the `carbon-components-react` library.

```js
handleChange = evt => {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.value, this.props.name, evt);
};
```

[source](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-react/blob/master/src/components/RadioButton/RadioButton.js#L92-L94)

The code shows that the event is passed as the third argument, following the contents of the `value` and `name` props of the `RadioButton` component.

So you should be able to handle changes like this:

```
handleChange(value, name, event) {
        console.log(event)
        const {type, checked} = event.target // Should not be needed anymore.
        this.setState({[name]: value})
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Rallen, that was a big help.  It does still leave a dilemma, but with a workaround:

I am trying to use the same handleChange function for every element on my form.  Since some elements are returning the event object in the first parameter, while others return it in the third, I am switching to "handleChange1()" and "handleChange2()".  Not ideal, but it works.  :-)

Thanks again!